# Angular ng-click does not work in Kendo UI template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm trying to add ng-click into Kedo UI template, but function **saveCustomView** on **theUser** controller still cannot be fired.

But outside of the  tag is ng-click working correctly.

```
<div id="grid" data-ng-controller="UsersCtrl" data-ng-init="initGrid()" >
    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="testBtn" >
        <div class="toolbar">
            <a data-ng-controller="UsersCtrl"
                ng-click="saveCustomView()">
                Add actual selection to custom views
            </a>
        </div>
    </script>
```

Could somebody tell me how can I solve it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is that template included?

Comment: Yes button is displayed.

Comment: Why is the controller also defined in the <a> tag?

Comment: Because i tried to move tag outside from parent tag. It has no  affect the result.