# Kendo template not firing Angular ng-click

Tags: angularjs, datagrid, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have this template inside of my datagrid:

```
<div id="grid" data-ng-controller="UsersCtrl" data-ng-init="initGrid()" >

        <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="preparedViewsToolbar" ng-init="initPreparedViews()">
            <div class="toolbar">
                <!-- SAVE CUSTOM VIEW BTN -->
                <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-save-changes"
                   data-ng-controller="UsersCtrl"
                   ng-click="showCustomViewModal();">
                    Add actual selection to custom views
                </a>
            </div>
        </script>
    </div>
```

I injecting template inside of the datagrid toolbar:

```
  { template: kendo.template($("#preparedViewsToolbar").html()) },
```

Template is correctly displayed in datagrid but after click is not firing predefined action on controller.

I tried to find any working solutions for a few hours, but without luck.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Why did you add a WPF tag to this question, or please explain how you think it relates to WPF?

Comment: You've already asked this question before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24487794/2701144

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions about the same issue; you can edit your original question to add more information.